# What is the easiest way to get an HTTP response from command-line Dart?

Tags: dart

I am writing a command-line script in Dart. What's the easiest way to access (and GET) an HTTP resource?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [http package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) for easy command-line access to HTTP resources. While the core `dart:io` library has the primitives for HTTP clients (see [HttpClient](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpClient.html)), the http package makes it much easier to GET, POST, etc.

First, add http to your pubspec's dependencies:

```yaml
name: sample_app
description: My sample app.
dependencies:
  http: any
```

Install the package. Run this on the command line or via Dart Editor:

```
pub install
```

Import the package:

```dart
// inside your app
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Make a GET request. The `get()` function returns a `Future`.

```dart
http.get('http://example.com/hugs').then((response) => print(response.body));
```

It's best practice to return the Future from the function that uses `get()`:

```dart
Future getAndParse(String uri) {
  return http.get('http://example.com/hugs')
      .then((response) => JSON.parse(response.body));
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any formal docs. So I had to look through the code (which does have good comments): https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/trunk/dart/pkg/http/lib/http.dart

Answer (score 0):

this is the shortest code i could find

```
curl -sL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" "URL" -o /dev/null
```

Here, -s silences curl's progress output, -L follows all redirects as before, -w prints the report using a custom format, and -o redirects curl's HTML output to /dev/null.

Here are the other special variables available in case you want to customize the output some more:

- url_effective
- http_code
- http_connect
- time_total
- time_namelookup
- time_connect
- time_pretransfer
- time_redirect
- time_starttransfer
- size_download
- size_upload
- size_header
- size_request
- speed_download
- speed_upload
- content_type
- num_connects
- num_redirects
- ftp_entry_path

Comment: Thanks! But the question was specifically how to fetch an HTTP resource from within a Dart application. This is good to know, though.