# HttpRequest with dart (broken/failed language)

Tags: httprequest, dart

I have this code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();      

}
```

without doing anything else, I get a yellow line under HttpRequest(); that says 'Abstract classes cannot be instantiated with 'new' ...' blah blah. I copied and pasted this code directly from https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/misc/tQsptp_PprU.  It was posted on april 12th 2013, so it can't possibly be outdated. i downloaded the newest version of the dart editor just today.

continuing on, i can then type `request.` and a list of available methods will come up. `open()` is not one of them. is this language just half-assed or is the editor this bad?

Comment: How are you planning on using this - as an HttpClient, or in an HttpServer?

Comment: an httpclient. i want to experiment with different languages as scripting languages in the same capacity as python/php/perl are capable of.

Comment: Sure thing - have a look at my answer below. Seth's question/answer shows how to use the http package to do this. The http package is definately the easiest way to do this, the built in io.HttpRequest class is quite low-level.

Answer (score 4):

There is no public empty constructor for the [io.HttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpRequest.html) class.

The link you've posted is using [html.HttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html), which has a different API.

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734057/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-an-http-response-from-command-line-dart) may help you.